# Where to store user passcode for auth with React Native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm building a React Native app at the moment. I want to display an 'auth' page when the app detects a user is logged in, to allow them to access the app when they open it - similar to how Face ID / Touch ID would be used to allow access when a signed in user opens an app.

On this 'auth' page, I want to offer the user the ability to enter a passcode to access the application if Face ID / Touch ID doesn't work.

But where do I store this passcode?

It seems counter-intuitive to save it in local device storage, unless this is stored upon successful sign-in, and is only deleted upon sign-out.

But then I'd need to store this somewhere, like a database. So only upon sign-in does this database get queried and the details then get saved into local storage, saving API requests going every time the user wants to access the app. But this also feels a little bit iffy, it seems sensible but not as slick as it probably should be.

What are the common industry practices, and what other options could I pursue?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when user logs in you have to generate authentication token from your backend then you will store that token with the [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) package with `AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)`. Whenever a user returns to your app you will get that token with `AsyncStorage.getItem(value)` and validate it from your backend.

If you must save the passcode then you can still use same package to store the passcode in the device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think I've explained it very well - I'm using Firebase for my Auth, so don't need to worry about tokens. But, I want a way once the user is signed in to prove it's them. Usually when you're signed in to an app, it'll prompt Face ID / Touch ID / Passcode when you open it for added security. I want to know where I store this passcode in this situation. It needs to be persisted somewhere, but where is my question.

Comment: With firebase authentication, you can listen to onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
//if user is not null then you're logged on, otherwise you're logged off.
}); No need to save passcode.